# Get currentUser not working with firestore and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've created a simple sign-up in which the user provides their name, bio, and profile picture. Currently, I am trying to display a logged-in user's data, however, I'm not having much luck doing so.

The issue here is that the data is not being retrieved (from the fact that my console only prints out "nothing"). I used the firestore documentation to create the `getUser()` function and am at a loss as to why it doesn't work.

```
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/authContext";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/storage";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
```

```
  async function getUser() {
    const userRef = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    userRef.get().then(function (doc) {
      if (!doc.exists) { 
        console.log("nothing");
      } else {
        console.log("document", doc.data().name);
      }
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, [])
```

I've tried a lot of different methods, but none of which are giving me the results I want. I've attempted to use `reactfire` but I am in the process of debugging that as well. I've been researching this for days and feel clueless. Thanks for any input you can provide, I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code here looks to be fine (aside from the floating promises and not handling the component being attached/detached). Ensure that `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` is returning the right ID, and then go to the Firebase console and check if that user's document actually exists under that ID.

Comment: Additionally, you should avoid using the `firebase/compat` libraries and use the modern APIs. The compatibility layer was to help move legacy code to the new format and shouldn't be used for new projects.

Comment: @samthecodingman thank you for the advice! I will update those libraries. The `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` does return the right ID and the ID does correspond to an actual user in firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@samthecodingman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3068190/samthecodingman) suggested, we should not use compact libraries for new projects.Here’s one example with the new modular Firebase API.

I had one context based example : Here Data component is wrapped inside AuthProvider in App.tsx:
**AuthProvider.tsx**:

```
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  User,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import React from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../config/firebase";

type ContextType = {
  user: User | null;
  loading: boolean;
  login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<User>;
  register: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<User>;
  logOut: () => Promise<void>;
  getUserData: () => Promise<void>
};

const AuthContext = React.createContext({} as ContextType);

export function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = React.useState<User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  async function login(email: string, password: string) {
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  async function register(email: string, password: string) {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  async function getUserData() {
    if(auth.currentUser) {
      console.log("User: ", auth.currentUser);
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser?.uid);
      const data = await getDoc(userRef);
      if(!data.exists()) console.log("Not Found");
      else console.log("User Data Found: ", data.data());
    }else console.log("User Not Found");
  }

  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    user: currentUser,
    loading: loading,
    login: login,
    register: register,
    logOut: logOut,
    getUserData: getUserData
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Data.tsx**:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./contexts/AuthProvider";

export default function Data() {
  const { login, getUserData, user, logOut, loading} = useAuth();

  async function onSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
      const user = await login("john@email.com", "password");
      console.log(user);
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(); //If user Logged in this will print UserData If not will print User Not Found
  }, [user])

  async function getData() {
    await getUserData();
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <button type="submit" disabled={loading}>Login</button>
      </form>
      <br />
      {user && JSON.stringify(user)}
      <br />
      <button onClick={getUserData}>Get Data</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={logOut}>Logout</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For more information you can follow [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) for handling users data and also take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/React-Firebase-Auth)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I added the `getUserData()` logic to my `AuthProvider.jsx` and tried to console.log the results and it shows as "Not Found" One step closer though, so I'll keep debugging

Comment: @user21317313 So Now you know that your user is not logged in if your are getting that message So make sure you logging in user correctly so automatically user will be there after login.

Comment: thank you! I actually followed this technique and my method works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: But the Firebase UI SDK doesn't support the modular SDK. No choice but to use the compat library!